# ApolloLink to Headless CMS / Cross Origin Domain (Wordpress WPGraphQL Endpoint) not Working: Apache 500 Error

Tags: apache, graphql, cross-domain, apollo, gatsby

Setup: I have a Gatsby project, which uses an ApolloLink to create a connection between the GraphQL endpoint of my headless CMS (Wordpress endpoint, generated through the [WPGraphQL plugin](https://www.wpgraphql.com/)) and my frontend. The fetch method uses "no-cors". My origin currently is localhost:8000, in production has to be a different domain then the backend-domain.

The problem: I have to host the frontend on Netlify, therefore front- and backend are on different domains. When I make the Apollo request to the headless CMS, the response headers return an error 500.

in gatsby-browser

```js
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://my-other-endpoint.com/graphql', 
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'http://localhost:8000'
  },
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link
});
```

graphql query:

```js
const TEST_QUERY = gql`
  query {competenceBy(competenceId:1067){date}}
`;
```

the component, which should render the data:

```js
const MyComp = (props) => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(TEST_QUERY, { errorPolicy: 'all' });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading Posts...</p>;

  if (error) {
    return (
      <p>
        graphQLErrors:
        <br />
        {error.graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => (
          <span>{message}</span>
        ))}
        <br />
        <br />
        {error.message}
      </p>
    )
  }

  const { page } = data;
  console.log("TCL: CompetencesPageTemplate -> page", page)

  return (
    <>
        {
          page.acf.content_competences
        }
    </>
  );

}

export default MyComp
```

in the .htaccess on my server:

```js
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure the CORS Header in your WPGraphQL request, try using the [WPGraphQL-CORS](https://github.com/funkhaus/wp-graphql-cors) plugin on your WordPress backend. It was designed for this very scenario.

[image: WPGraphQL-CORS Settings]